# Sort every Map in List by Set of keys

Tags: java, algorithm

I have `List` of `LinkedHashMap` like `List<Map<String, String>>`. Every `Map` has the same number of elements and every `Map` has the same keys.

The second element is `LinkedHashSet<String>` - set of keys.

Now I would like to order every `Map` from `List` by keys. Sort ordering is in `LinkedHashSet<String>`.

My attempt is iterate by `List<Map<String, String>>`. For every `Map` create new `Map` and iterate by `Set`. To the new `Map` put key and value from old `Map`where key is taken from `Set`. In code:

```
    private List<Map<String, String>> sort(List<Map<String,String> result, LinkedHashSet<String> keys){
        List<Map<String, String>> sortedResult = new LinkedList<>();
        result.forEach(map -> {
            Map<String, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            keys.forEach(key -> {
                sortedMap.put(key, map.get(key));
            });
            sortedResult.add(sortedMap);
        });
        return sortedResult;
    }
```

I think it is a little bit complicated and in my opinion there exsists better way to do that.

Comment: A `Set` does not have any particular order, so iterating over it will not follow a predictable order.

Comment: Sorry, that is `LinkedHashSet<String>`. I edited in main topic too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `LinkedHashMap` which tries to maintain only the order of insertion of keys, not the natural-ordering of keys. One thing you can do is to maintain a list of keys outside the map and sort them and re-insert the <key,value> pairs as per the order of the sorted list of keys. So it seems you are already doing this in your code by having an order defined by `LinkedHashSet`.

The other simple approach is:

If you want an ordered map by keys, you most probably need a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), insertion into this map maintains the natural ordering of keys and you can construct a treemap from an existing map.

```
    private List<Map<String, String>> sort(List<Map<String,String> result) {
      List<Map<String, String>> sortedResult = new LinkedList<>();
      for ( Map<String, String> m : result )
          sortedResult.add(new TreeMap(m)));
      return sortedResult;
    }
```

BTW, *Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would change:

1. The argument name "result" is misleading. People going over the code quickly will think this is the returned result. I would change it to "unsortedMaps" or something similar
2. Each Map shouldn't affect the other so instead of **result.forEach** you could use  **result.parallelStream().forEach** to make every map sorted in it's own thread. You will need to make insertion to list itself thread safe (either surronding "sortedResult.add(sortedMap" with synchronized statment or use a thread-safe list implementation. All this doesn't guarantee improvement in performance. It depends on many variants such as the size of the collections and number of cores. Test it to find out.
3. There are a lot of details in this function. I would extract the part dealing with each map to a seperate function

Here is the result (didn't test the code so can't gurentee correctness. Needless to say unit-tests are always the way to go):

```
    private List<Map<String, String>> sort(List<Map<String,String>> unsortedMaps, LinkedHashSet<String> keys){
        List<Map<String, String>> sortedResult = new LinkedList<>();
        unsortedMaps.parallelStream().forEach(map -> {
            Map<String, String> sortedMap = getSortedMap(keys, map);
            synchronized (sortedResult) {
                sortedResult.add(sortedMap);
            }
        });
        return sortedResult;
    }

    private Map<String, String> getSortedMap(LinkedHashSet<String> keys, Map<String, String> map) {
        Map<String, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        keys.forEach(key -> {
            sortedMap.put(key, map.get(key));
        });
        return sortedMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete SomeDude answer, if the natural order isn't enough for your need, you can try to specify a Comparator to the TreeMap :

```
private List<Map<String, String>> sort(List<Map<String,String>> mapList, Set<String> keys){
    List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>(keys);
    return mapList.stream().map(map -> copyAndReOrderMap(map, keysList)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Map<String, String> copyAndReOrderMap(Map<String, String> map, List<String> keysList) {
    Map<String, String> orderedMap = new TreeMap<>((key1, key2) -> Integer.compare(keysList.indexOf(key1), keysList.indexOf(key2))); 
    orderedMap.putAll(map);
    return orderedMap;
}
```

NB: Unless you deal with very large maps, i don't see why you would want to sort each map in a separate Thread.